Laravel Filament v3 Form Tab content gets misplaced
I have got an issue with a form builder. My form consists of multiple tabs with where various tabs and/or form elements get shown/hidden depending on live form data. I have noticed that the last tab content gets misplaced depending on form input states.
Even though the original problem I had was on a real project, where we have quite a complex form, I have managed to reproduce it using a simplified sample form. I am not sure whether it is a Filament bug, Livewire bug or just an user error. I hope you can share your thoughts.
I have created a fresh repository https://github.com/mariusaustr/filamentphp-tabs-bug where you can clone it down, follow steps in readme.md to set the project up, view more unexpected behaviour screenshots & reproduce the bug (?). Since the bug can be reproduced in a fresh repository, I think cache or out of date dependencies are out of question.
The Problem:
When you check 2  live() checkboxes in Details tab, the form element from the last tab gets displayed at the bottom of every tab.
When you uncheck those 2 live() checboxes - the last tab form component goes missing
If you delete any of those 4 tabs, the issue disappears.
Form Definition:
https://github.com/mariusaustr/filamentphp-tabs-bug/blob/main/app/Filament/Resources/UserResource.php
public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        $categories = [
            'Category1',
            'Category2',
            'Category3',
        ];
        
        $modelData = [];
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $modelData[$category] = [
                'available' => false,
                'option_1' => false,
                'option_2' => false,
            ];
        }

        return $form
            ->schema([
                Tabs::make('Tabs')
                    ->columnSpanFull()
                    ->tabs([

                        Tab::make('Control')
                            ->schema(
                                collect($modelData)
                                    ->mapWithKeys(fn (array $data, string $category) => [
                                        $category => Fieldset::make($category)
                                            ->columns(3)
                                            ->schema(
                                                (new Collection($data))
                                                    ->mapWithKeys(function ($value, $key) use ($category) {
                                                        return [
                                                            $key => Forms\Components\Checkbox::make("categories.{$category}.{$key}")
                                                                ->hidden(fn (Get $get): bool => $key !== 'available' && ! $get("categories.{$category}.available"))
                                                                ->default($value)
                                                                ->live(condition: in_array($key, ['available', 'option_2']))
                                                        ];
                                                    })
                                                    ->toArray()
                                            ),
                                    ])
                                    ->toArray()
                            ),

                        Tab::make('Hidden Dummy Tab 1')
                            ->hidden(fn (Get $get): bool => (new Collection($get('categories')))
                                    ->filter(fn (array $data) => $data['available'])
                                    ->filter(fn (array $data) => $data['option_2'])
                                    ->isEmpty()
                            )
                            ->schema([
                                Fieldset::make('Dummy fields of conditionally hidden tab')
                                    ->schema([
                                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('www.up'),
                                    ]),
                            ]),

                        Tab::make('Empty Dummy Tab 3')
                            ->schema([
                                Fieldset::make('Hidden Dummy fields')
                                    ->hidden(fn (Get $get): bool => (new Collection($get('categories')))
                                        ->filter(fn (array $data) => $data['available'])
                                        ->filter(fn (array $data) => $data['option_2'])
                                        ->isEmpty()
                                    )
                                    ->schema([
                                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('abc.def'),
                                    ]),
                            ]),

                        Tab::make('Dummy Tab 4')
                            ->schema([
                                Fieldset::make('Dummy fieldset from last tab')
                                    ->schema([
                                        Forms\Components\Checkbox::make('todo.check'),
                                    ]),
                            ]),
                    ]),
            ]);
    }

More details in https://github.com/mariusaustr/filamentphp-tabs-bug
Is it something I am doing wrong? oris this filament/livewire bug?
Any ideas would be much appreciated.
